# Is it possible to run jQAssistant Dashboard on a standalone Neo4J server?

Tags: jqassistant

We have an external Neo4J database running as service. Can I install the jQAssistant Dashboard onto that server?

Comment: can you provide a bit more context? how do you run Neo4j database? is it a self-hosted VM, Docker-based, app engine, cloud SaaS offering?

Comment: We were running Neo4j as a standard installation on a running RHEL server. But unfortunately, nobody here is really interested in jQAssistant, so I removed it since.